# Writing a code that finds divisibility of a number (java)?

Tags: java

So, I'm supposed to write a program that checks if the inputted value is divisible by 2,3,4,5,6,8, and/or 9. 
I'm getting a red error when I run this program. It's an index out of bounds exception and it says 
"`at Divisibility.div2(Divisibility.java:29) at Divisibility.main(Divisibility.java:11)`

How do I fix this?

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Divisibility
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter number:  ");
        int num=scan.nextInt();
        ArrayList<Integer>di=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<String>a=new ArrayList<String>();
        div2(di);
        div3(di);
        div4(num);
        div5(di);
        div6(di);
        div8(num);
        while(num>0) 
        {
            di.add(num%10);
            num/=10; 
        }
        for(int i=0;i<di.size();i++)
        {
            a.add(""+di.get(i)); 
        }
    }
    public static void div2(ArrayList<Integer> arr)
    {
        if(arr.get(0)==2||arr.get(0)==4||arr.get(0)==6||arr.get(0)==8||arr.get(0)==0)
        {
            System.out.println("Divisible by 2"); 
        }
    }
    public static void div3(ArrayList<Integer> ar1)
    {
        int t=0;
        for(int i=0;i<ar1.size();i++)
        {
            t+=ar1.get(i); 
            if(t%3==0)
            {
                System.out.println("Divisible by 3");
                i=ar1.size();
            }
        }
    }
    public static void div4(int br)
    {
        String str=Integer.toString(br);
        String str2=str.substring(str.length()-2,str.length());
        int r=Integer.parseInt(str2);
        if(r%4==0)
            System.out.print("Divisible by 4");
    }
    public static void div5(ArrayList<Integer> ah)
    {
        if(ah.get(0)==0||ah.get(0)==5)
        {
            System.out.println("Divisible by 5"); 
        }
    }
    public static void div6(ArrayList<Integer> q)
    {
        int l=0;
        for(int i=0;i<q.size();i++)
        {
            l+=q.get(i); 
            if(l%3==0&&(q.get(0)==2||q.get(0)==4||q.get(0)==6||q.get(0)==8||q.get(0)==0))
            {
                System.out.print("Divisible by 6");
                i=q.size();
            }
        }
    }
    public static void div8(int na)
    {
        String str1=Integer.toString(na);
        String str3=str1.substring(str1.length()-3,str1.length());
        int rr=Integer.parseInt(str3);
        if(rr%8==0)
            System.out.print("Divisible by 8");
    }
    public static void div9(ArrayList<Integer> bruh)
    {
        int y=0;
        for(int i=0;i<bruh.size();i++)
        {
            y+=bruh.get(i); 
            if(y%9==0)
            {
                System.out.println("Divisible by 9");
                i=bruh.size();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `ArrayList<Integer>di=new ArrayList<Integer>();` is empty arraylist. try `di.add(num)`.

Comment: I'm assuming that there are constraints on how you are supposed to tackle this problem since you are clearly familiar with the remainder `%` operator.  I recommend you edit your question and explain those constraints so you don't get a flurry of answers.

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling the `div2` method, you have not yet added any thing to

```
ArrayList<Integer>di=new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

This is a declaration only.

You do not add until

```
while(num>0) 
  {
    di.add(num%10);
    num/=10; 
 }
```

This adding needs to be done before calling the `div?` methods